# Zyxel Router Static IP setup

Tags: networking, nat, static-ip

I need assistance with a static ip setup.
The router is set up with the details for the static IP and the computer is able to browse the Internet and able to ping the static IP.
The problem that comes in when I try to connect via remote desktop, it will not connect.
I might need to set up NAT, but am struggling with that part.
Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right so firstly external or internal static IP? Really you need both but definitely the PC needs a static IP. Secondly you need to setup remote desktop on the PC to accept connections. Thirdly you need to forward port 3389 on your Zyxel Router to your PC's static IP. If you can browse the internet then I would say 99% sure NAT is already up and running.

Comment: Add some more details from what I wrote above (like model of Zyxel, etc.) and I will try to add an answer to guide you the rest of the way...

Comment: @CharlesH Port forwarding is configuring NAPT which is a form of NAT, so I suppose she could call it setting up NAT [for remote desktop to work].  RFC 3022 says "Basic NAT and NAPT are two variations of traditional NAT," RFC 2662  says similarly.

Comment: @CharlesH thanks for the responses, it most likely is the port forward for port 3389. I have already set the computer to accept connections for remote desktop. It is an external static ip and the router is a Zyxel Sbg3300